# How many yellow cards before player is suspended in Copa del Rey

Tags: rules, football, suspension

How many yellow cards will get player suspended in Spanish [Copa del Rey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copa_del_Rey).

Answer (score 3):

Accumulating three cautions in the Copa del Rey will see a player suspended for one match.

On page 5 of [RFEF 2017/18 Circular No 5](http://cdn1.sefutbol.com/sites/default/files/circular5.pdf) [pdf]:

> Tratándose del Campeonato de España/Copa de S.M el Rey, del torneo Copa Real Federación Española de Fútbol y de la segunda fase o de ascenso del Campeonato de Liga de Segunda, Segunda "B" y Tercera divisiones, los ciclos que causurán la suspensión serán de tres amonestaciones.

I believe this roughly translates to:

> In the Copa del Rey (Spanish Championship), the Copa Federacion, and the promotion play-offs of the Segunda Division, Segunda Division B, and Tercera Division, accumulating three cautions will result in a suspension.